# Access secured Oracle NoSql DB using JPA

Tags: security, jpa, eclipselink, oracle-nosql

I am trying to access Oracle NoSql DB using JPA (api - org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider).

I am facing two issues :

1. How to secure my Oracle NoSql store using just basic authentication
   (login/password only) ?

Oracle docs at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/SecurityGuide/secure_installation.html seems to be helpful but I don't need so much security overheads.

2. How to access this secured data-store using JPA, two properties I came across are: "eclipselink.nosql.property.user", "eclipselink.nosql.property.password". Are they valid for Oracle NoSql DB ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am also trying to coonect to a secured NoSQL KVSTORE but getting error "run failed: Insufficient access rights granted"